# landscape layout does not change on orientation change and portain layout does not change in orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait

i have two layouts here one is portrait and one is landscape the landscape is located in the layout-land folder and the the portrait is located in the layout folder both have the same name. what i want to do here is that when the emulator screen is portrait it will load portrait and when the screen is landscape it will load a landscape layout but it is not happening when the first view is portrait and when i change orientation it still loads the portrait layout in landscape view and when its landscape first and i change orientation to portrait it loads the landscape layout on portrait screen what seems to be the problem here.

portrait code: http://pastebin.com/QSVL2MHf
landscape code: http://pastebin.com/ktGAe0QX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` section for this particular `Activity`.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" this is what i have in the manifest should i replace it  android:configChanges="screenSize"?

Comment: yes. the `orientation` is preventing the Activity to re-create.

Comment: it is ok if i remove all the android:configChanges="orientation" for all activity will it have a big effect on the activity i mean will it still run they way it is now?

Comment: normally, there is no reason to put there it in the first place. so it depends on your app. just give it a try. why did **you** set it?

Comment: when im in portrait it loads portrait and when i change to landscape it still loads portrait layout..actually i didnt set it it was there when i made the first activity so i retain it for all activity

Comment: any others ideas?im really out of ideas why it wont load

Comment: remove the whole configChanges part. and debug your code.

Comment: i already tried it before you said it first i remove the orientation then i totally remove but nothing changed